# Android boolean resource not being recognized as a bool, but as an int

Tags: android, android-resources

I am writing an `Android` app and have an issue with defining a `boolean` resource.

I have a file, `bools.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="preferences_autoplay">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Yet when I try to use `R.bool.preferences_autoplay`, it is recognized as an `int` and not a `boolean`:

[image]

And I get the error:

The method `putBoolean(String, boolean)` in the type `SharedPreferences.Editor` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, int)`

I can certainly make due with using an `int` if I need to, but I don't understand why it isn't recognized as a `boolean`.

Any thoughts on how to use a `boolean` resource as a `boolean`?

Comment: R.java has references to each of your resources (no matter of what type they are) as int

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The generated `R` fields refer to the ID of the specified boolean (or other types). You can resolve the actual value using [Resources.getBoolean](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getBoolean%28int%29). E.g.:

```
boolean ap = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.preferences_autoplay);
```

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm and makes perfect sense. Slowly picking up this android business. Thanks.